# XmlHttpRequest cannot load because it is blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, cors

How do I create the origin header so that it works for all domains and browsers on all devices? Do I use some kind of callback? Where in my code do I place this?

```
var characters = [

"http://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/148",
"http://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/823",
"http://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/1052",
"http://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/1303",
"http://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/208",

];



$(".btn").click(clickButton);


function clickButton(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var i = $(this).attr("data-id");
console.log(characters[i]);

var data;

$.getJSON(characters[i], function(json) {
    data = json;

)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try invoking the API via HTTPS instead of HTTP it will work ( i tried right now ).

You're getting that error message, because the server is sending a redirect response ( `HTTP/1.1 301` .. see the `Location` header ), without CORS headers. As you can see here:

```
 $ curl -v http://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/148
 *   Trying 104.27.137.190...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * Connected to www.anapioficeandfire.com (104.27.137.190) port 80 (#0)
 GET /api/characters/148 HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.anapioficeandfire.com
 User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
 Accept: */*
 
 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
 Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 21:43:13 GMT
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: keep-alive
 Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d59cc58d4e217f93147944a7f5ae1b6231495402993; expires=Mon, 21-May-18 21:43:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.anapioficeandfire.com; HttpOnly
 Cache-Control: max-age=3600
 Expires: Sun, 21 May 2017 22:43:13 GMT
 Location: https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/148
 Server: cloudflare-nginx
 CF-RAY: 362ab5c495ec42fe-MXP
```

The browser is then blocking the second request ( the one that would actually follow the redirect ) for that reason.

You can dig a little bit deeper into what CORS actually is here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

### Code Example

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/148', function (json) {
   $('#api-response').text(JSON.stringify(json,null,4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="api-response"></pre>
```

Let me recommend you to read a bit more about HTTP, Ajax and Javascript to get a better understanding of whats going on. This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: How do you invoke the API via HTTPS instead of HTTP? Do I use the command line? Will it work for all browsers? I tried doing that and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try to use something similar to my code example if you can

Comment: Im still getting the same answer as before. Here is my current site now: http://pbcs.us/~falcantara/projects/jquery/

Comment: @FrederickAlcantara you're still using HTTP. Look the urls you're using in your array ( var characters = [ ... ] )

Comment: How do I change those URLs to HTTPS? Was it going to back to what you were doing from before?

Comment: Is that code written by you? if it is then just edit the strings in the characters array. Replace ```http://anapiof...``` with ```https://anapiof....```

Comment: I'm having an getting the 4th item in the array. Everything else works fine. The only one that doesn't work is characters/1303. The API says it's available but I can't get it. Why is that?

Comment: @FrederickAlcantara This answer is the correct answer for your question and you should mark it as Accepted https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @FrederickAlcantara No idea. This questions you're making right know have nothing to do with the original one, and are strictly related to your application. Try studying a little bit more, you look pretty confused about what you're doing. As i said in my answer, take a look at what HTTP is, try to understand Javascript better, look what Ajax is. Once you have a good knowledge about all that then start looking into HTTP APIs and so on. All this things are well documented on the internet. Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you at least explain why it works browsers like firefox and safari but not on opera or chrome? Would that be an issue with the browser or something else?

Comment: Again, read the docs about CORS, i gave you a link, it's not a browser "issue" is a feature and it's there for security reasons. What i wrote in my answer is true for all major browsers ( Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safri and Opera). If there's anything else that's braking your app in any of those browser then find the problem, search for a solution. If you can't find anything about your problem make a new question here and someone will be happy to help you.